# Arabic not urlencoding correctly

Tags: php, character-encoding, arabic, url-encoding

I have the string:

```
$str = 'ماجد';
```

This need to be encoded as:

```
'%E3%C7%CC%CF'
```

But I cannot figure out how to reach this encoded string. I believe it is Windows-1256. The above encoded string is how it is being encoded by a program I have.

Does anyone know how to reach this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you want to use `Windows-1256` then all you have to do is to change the encoding of the input string (which is `UTF-8`) to `Windows-1256`. Then you apply [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to the returned string and that's all.

There are several ways to change the encoding of a string in PHP. One of them (that I tested and provides the result you expect) is using [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
$str  = 'ماجد';
$conv = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1256', $str);
echo(urlencode($conv));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. Spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow split the string into its hexadecimal representation and then put a `%` singn in front of the hex number pairs.

```
<?php

$hexString = bin2hex("ماجد");  
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexString); $i += 2){
    echo "%".substr($hexString, $i, 2);
}

?>
```

This will do the trick but im sure there is a more elegant way.